# how to display max date in set of three records using oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

hi 
 i am developing software for warehouse here the stocks will be unloaded for same party same bill no. on different dates but i have to capture the last unloaded date there may be so many bill no.s but i want one unloaded date for one bill no. even though the same bill no. have been unloaded on 3 or 4 days

my oracle statement is as follows

```
SELECT A.BE_NO,
       B.CUS_NAME,
       C.COMM_NAME,
       A.PKG_SIZE,
       SUM(A.TOT_QTY),
       SUM(A.AFTRISSBAL) AS BALAVBL
  FROM GDN_LOT A,
       CUSTOMERS B,
       COMM_MAST C
  GROUP BY A.BE_NO,
           B.CUS_NAME,
           C.COMM_NAME,
           A.PKG_SIZE,
           B.CUS_CODE,
           A.CUS_CODE,
           A.COMM_CODE,
           C.COMM_CODE,
           A.UNLOAD_DT
  HAVING B.CUS_CODE IN ('TTS','SSK') AND
         SUM(A.AFTRISSBAL)<>0 AND
         A.CUS_CODE=B.CUS_CODE AND
         A.COMM_CODE=C.COMM_CODE AND
         UNLOAD_DT<'06/Jan/2011'
  ORDER BY B.CUS_CODE;
```

plz advise on these

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear. I guess you want to replace the clause

```
UNLOAD_DT < '06/Jan/2011'
```

by something providing the max date of some set of dates... I'm not going to guess how the query could be rephrased, but I think that [Oracle Analytic Functions](http://psoug.org/reference/analytic_functions.html) might be of help to you.